# Changing pin color MKMapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I add annotations to my map in this way:

```
MyAnnotation *annotationPoint2 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint2.coordinate = anyLocation;
annotationPoint2.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj];
annotationPoint2.subtitle = @"";  //or set to nil
annotationPoint2.keyValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
[mapPins addAnnotation:annotationPoint2];
```

The pins are all red, and I would like them all green. How can I change the color? I have tried the following, but it still gives a red mark:

```
annotationPoint2.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation 
  {
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    return annView;
  }
```

Comment: this code works, but even the current user location becomes green, even if I want it blue with the circles round it. How can I do that?

Comment: if([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"]) 
   {   
     annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
   }else{annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;}

Comment: @Alessandro You need to return nil when annotation == mapView.userLocation to show the blue dot for user location and the circle around it

Comment: Remember to set the view's canShowCallout if you want the title/subtitle information to be displayed when the pin is touched

Answer (score 6):

The `pinColor` property is defined in the `MKPinAnnotationView` class (not the `MKAnnotation` protocol).

You create a `MKPinAnnotationView` in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.  If you haven't implemented that delegate, you get standard red pins by default.

In that delegate method, you create an instance of `MKPinAnnotationView` and you can set its `pinColor` to green.

Answer (score 5):

Swift3 is in this way:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")

    if annotation.title! == "My Place" {

        annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.green

    } else {

        annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor.red
    }


    return annotationView
}
```